# what OUTPUT_NAME is use for in cmake

Tags: cmake, mingw, gnu

code from CMakeFiles.txt
what's the reason of setting the propetties of OUTPUT_NAME

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(hello_static PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "hello")

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/OUTPUT_NAME.html#prop_tgt:OUTPUT_NAME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That controls the name of the actual file that's generated, independent from the target's name.

In this case, the file will be named `hello.a` or `hello.lib` instead of `hello_static.a` or `hello_static.lib`

See the documentation for the property: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/OUTPUT_NAME.html